# Is it possible to have arrays with more then one dimension in Basic4Android?

Tags: basic4android

in the docu I found

```
ARRAY -> creates arrays with one dimension
DIM a() as string -> Array with strings in one dimension
MAP -> 1 Key, 1 Data field
```

do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim TwoDimensions (3,3) As Double
Dim ThreeDimensions(3,3,3) As Double
```

This you can find from section 10.3.2 in Beginners Guide, which is available to download from:
http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/documentation.html